# "no caching mode page found" error in Ubuntu without any drive partition

Tags: 16.04

```
[6.913785] sd 1:0:0:0 [sdb] no caching mode page found 
[6.913885] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] assuming drve cache: write through
Busy box v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands 
Initramfs
```

Comment: New install? Or did this message just appear? More info, please.

Comment: "without any drive partition" You must have a "/",

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm guessing the OP means that the block device is unpartitioned i.e. `/` (and everything under it) is on `/dev/sdb` rather than `/dev/sdb*n*`

Comment: No this is already installed and I think  it appeared bcoz of my mistake as I change the crypt lugs format to NTFS and yes it is unpartitioned pls help me what to do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and I solved it according to the following steps:

1. I've created a USB key with the live of Mint distro and I booted the
   machine with it.
2. List your partitions using the following command:

> sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

I got the following output where sda the only drive on my machine, notice that your linux partition is /dev/sda1

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa71bc45b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 480393215 480391168 229.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       480395262 488396799   8001538   3.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       480395264 488396799   8001536   3.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

3. Then, I executed the following command which rescue my disk again

> sudo fsck -yv /dev/sda1

and I got the following result

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes

Inode 11275098 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11275099 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11275100 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11275101 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 11280599 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Error reading block 51389518 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading directory block.  Ignore error? yes

Force rewrite? yes

Directory inode 12855288, block #0, offset 0: directory corrupted
Salvage? yes

Missing '.' in directory inode 12855288.
Fix? yes

Setting filetype for entry '.' in ??? (12855288) to 2.
Missing '..' in directory inode 12855288.
Fix? yes

Setting filetype for entry '..' in ??? (12855288) to 2.
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
'..' in /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/efa5ec50cb7cda556e07082ce6f284bc89209ffc566a91212110072d83e73e91 (12855288) is <The NULL inode> (0), should be /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt (12468994).
Fix? yes

Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Inode 2 ref count is 23, should be 24.  Fix? yes

Inode 12468994 ref count is 58, should be 57.  Fix? yes

Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(45219840--45220206)
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #1380 (31392, counted=31759).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong (47147739, counted=46915808).
Fix? yes

Inode bitmap differences:  -(11275097--11275101) -11280599
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #1376 (5, counted=10).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #1377 (7279, counted=7280).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong (14328772, counted=14270663).
Fix? yes


/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

      745273 inodes used (4.96%, out of 15015936)
        2132 non-contiguous files (0.3%)
         607 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 698409/204
    13133088 blocks used (21.87%, out of 60048896)
           0 bad blocks
           3 large files

      607356 regular files
       89743 directories
          56 character device files
          25 block device files
           0 fifos
       41620 links
       48079 symbolic links (46566 fast symbolic links)
           5 sockets
------------
      786884 files
```

4. Finally, my machine worked fine without re installation.