# I can't install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, lubuntu

I recently had a problem with ubuntu and I decided to format the hard drive with ***DBAN*** and when reinstalling ubuntu, I could not because I received this message:

```
[sdb] No Caching mode page found
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Later I tried to install Lubuntu and I got the same error.

My (linux) pc specs:

- Intel i3 3,6 Gz
- Nvidia Gt 730
- 2Gb Ram

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/821674/no-caching-mode-page-found-error-in-ubuntu-without-any-drive-partition for a solution.