# "no caching mode page found" error in Ubuntu mate booting

Tags: boot, mate

Since a few days ago my machine is a bit unsteady and I got these few lines at booting (among others that always appeared saying; mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)":

```
sd 1:0:0:0 [sdb] no caching mode page found 
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] assuming drive cache: write through
```

I saw a possible solution in: https://askubuntu.com/a/884027/1619780 , but I am not sure if this is going to wipe my disk or if after doing it I will keep my files. I will do a backup just in case but I would like to avoid reinstall everything rigth now. In the solution is said "machine worked fine without re-installation" but still not a hundred sure if he meant to talk about the OS or OS+personal files.

Also, if any idea of the meaning of the other lines that appear... would be very appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Those are notices, not errors. And both are NORMAL if your hard disk has no RAM for caching IIRC (I believe it was something like that).  And sdb is not the system I would assume? If so it will not be the cause of "Since a few days ago my machine is a bit unsteady".

Comment: Regarding "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)" that notice has nothing to do with the other parts. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1420416/15811 for a possible fix.